# Why does defaultValue have type any ? - TextField Material UI

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

In the Material UI guidelines, for the component `TextField`, it is written than its `defaulValue` takes `any` as type. https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

I played with it a bit:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-benz-7vj06 and it does seem that `defaulValue` takes several types.
I would like to know what is the rational behind defaulValue to have type `any`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's because setting `defaultValue` to values such as: `string` `number` `undefined` `null` and `array` which would be converted using `toString` method is normal and it makes sense using type `any` instead of all these types.